# How to get records without metadata in aerospike

Tags: python, aerospike

```
config = {'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 3000)]}

client = aerospike.client(config).connect()


def print_result(record):
    print(record)
```

try:

```
query = client.query('test_test', 'demo')
query.select('email')
query.where(p.between('id', 1, 25))
query.foreach(print_result)
```

this is my sample code of aerospike in python client , i am getting records with metadata how to get only records without metadata

Answer (score 1):

by giving print(record[2])
we'll get only records.

Comment: You'll get only bins. The record is the tuple of (key, metadata, bins). The bins aren't the record, they're the data portion of the record. The record is that tuple.